# File Watcher generate .css file but don't refresh browser and don't apply CSS code

Tags: css, sass, jetbrains-ide, rider, file-watcher

All my colleagues work on Visual Studio (me too before one week), but I switched to Rider. After setup my project I setup file watcher to compile SCSS to CSS.

But I have weird issue when I change something in my SCSS file everything compiles to CSS file, but my page stays the same and doesn't get newly created code from CSS. In Visual Studio we use web compiler and it works great: after any change browser refreshes and get new code.

What do I need to do to use file watcher like web compiler? I really like Rider and didn't want to go back to Visual Studio.

Comment: Can you try to clear your cache with Ctrl + F5 and see if it works?

Comment: yeah i tried everything with cache and other such things. Nothing change.

Comment: as, according to you, the .css file is successfully generated, it's not about file watcher - it works as expected, compiling your SCSS to CSS. Make sure that the folder the CSS is generated in is a folder the CSS is served from by your web server. Actually the page refreshing (hot reload) on files changing is a feature that is implemented on the server end - this is a web server that is responsible for this